# how to prove that $NP \cap co - NP$ = { S | S such that there exist a Strong Deciding Algorithm for S}?

Tags: complexity-theory, computability, np, co-np

i need to prove that and i find it struggle:
given:

for deciding problem S:

a non deterministic algorithm $A(x)$ is strong deciding algorithm if:

1. $x \in S =>$ fo every run of $A(x)$ returns "Yes" or "Maybe", and there exist run which $A(x)$ returns "Yes"
2. $x \notin S =>$ for every run of $A(x)$ returns "No" or "Maybe", and there exist run which $A(x)$ returns "No"

now we need to prove i assume with equality between two sets that

$NP \cap co - NP$ = { S | S such that there exist a Strong Deciding Algorithm for S}

thank you,

Comment: Hi, can you share with us your progress on this?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I managed to solve it finally it was very easy by the way